# How do I combine a tar, and a gzipped tar into a gzipped tar?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, gzip, tar

I have two different objects:

- archive1.tar.gz - a gzipped tarball of txt files
- archive2.tar - an unzipped tarball of txt files

I'd like to combine them into a single gzipped tarball with all the txt files at the same level as each other (i.e. no tarballs within tarballs), ideally without explicitly extracting them both and creating a whole new archive (which is my current workaround).

I'm using cshell, but I'd be happy with a bash solution if that's easier.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: All I can think of is gunzip `archive1` and then use `tar --concatenate --file=archive1.tar archive2.tar`.

Comment: @yorodm has it, could be posted as an answer, though this question is not appropriate for SO.

Comment: @Adrian is right, can someone move this to [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/) or something like that?

Comment: Super user would be the place for it, since it's not server related.

Answer (score 2):

The solution in my comment is fine, but I think this might suit you better.

```
zcat archive1.tar.gz archive2.tar | gzip > concatenated.tar.gz
```

Comment: I always forget about the z tools, good answer.